# Arduino C Why is my program calculating time incorrectly

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I have written a small program in arduino c which takes in time values for 3 different races in the order seconds, minutes hours, for a Swim, Bike and Run race. These values are taken in through the serial. They then should be converted into seconds and then the appropriate time by the program.

I've looked over and rewritten segments of my code and cannot find the issue.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(".");
  Serial.println("Please input your time values as follows: seconds, minutes, hours, for the swim, the bike, and the run.");
  long SecsMinsHoursSBR[9];
  const int NumberOfEvents = 3;

  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  {
    SecsMinsHoursSBR[i] = ReadLine();
  }

  int ToSecs[4];
  ToSecs[0] = (SecsMinsHoursSBR[2]*3600) + (SecsMinsHoursSBR[1]*60) + SecsMinsHoursSBR[0];
  ToSecs[1] = (SecsMinsHoursSBR[5]*3600) + (SecsMinsHoursSBR[4]*60) + SecsMinsHoursSBR[3];
  ToSecs[2] = (SecsMinsHoursSBR[8]*3600) + (SecsMinsHoursSBR[7]*60) + SecsMinsHoursSBR[6];
  ToSecs[3] = ToSecs[0] + ToSecs[1] + ToSecs[2];
  String Race[4] = {"Swim", "Bike", "Run", "Total"};

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfEvents; i++)
  {
    Serial.println(Race[i] + " Total:  ");
    Serial.print("Hour:");
    Serial.println(ToSecs[i] / 3600);
    Serial.print("Minutes:");
    Serial.println((ToSecs[i] % 3600) / 60);
    Serial.print("Seconds:");
    Serial.println((ToSecs[i] % 3600) % 60); 
  }


}

  int ReadLine(){
    Serial.println("Please input your value:");
    while (!Serial.available()){
      ;
    }
    int x = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.println(x);
    return x;
  }

void loop() {
  
}
```

Comment: `int` is 16 bits on most Arduinos, so its max value is `32,767`, If your values are larger than that, use `unsigned long`.

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: Please explain "not working". Show some example input and output.

Answer (score 0):

```
int ToSecs[4];
```

you want to store the values into an array ToSecs, specified as an "int"- Array. Numbers must be between +/-32767, this would be about 9 hours.

You have to change this into long or unsigned long to store values up to 68 or 136 Years